# Trying to obtain a % of discount

Tags: php, sql

I´m trying to obtain a % of discount.

The problem is when ventas_necesarias is 1 then I obtain 0 as discount.

```
    //Primero consultamos el numero de ordenes necesarias para aplicar la      bonificacion y el porcentaje
    $sql = "SELECT 
        (SELECT valor FROM lc_t_configuracion where id_conf = 18) as  ventas_necesarias, 
            (SELECT valor FROM lc_t_configuracion where id_conf = 19) as porcentaje_bonificacion,
            (SELECT (ventas_acumuladas) FROM lc_t_usuarios where id_usuario    = $_SESSION[id_usuario]) as ventas_acumuladas
            ";

    $respuesta = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql) or     die(mysqli_error($conexion));

    $datos_promocion = mysqli_fetch_array($respuesta, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

    //print_r($datos_promocion);
    $bono = 0;

    //si las ventas acumuladas son mayores o iguales a las necesarias se     aplica la promocion
    if($datos_promocion['ventas_acumuladas'] >=     $datos_promocion['ventas_necesarias'] && $_SESSION['tipo_usuario'] == 'C' &&     $_SESSION['cliente_vip'] == "N"){
        //echo "es mayor o igual que lo necesario";
        $limit = $datos_promocion['ventas_necesarias'] - 1;

        $sql = "SELECT 
                    ROUND(((SUM(total) + $_POST[total])  *     ($datos_promocion[porcentaje_bonificacion]/100)),0) as total
                FROM
                    (
                        SELECT 
                            total
                        FROM
                            lc_t_ordenes
                        WHERE
                            id_usuario = $_SESSION[id_usuario]
                        ORDER BY id_orden DESC
                        LIMIT $limit
                    ) AS t1";

        $respuesta = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql) or     die(mysqli_error($conexion));

        $bono = mysqli_fetch_array($respuesta);

        $bono = $bono['total'];

        $sql = "INSERT INTO `lc_t_preordenes`
                (
                    `id_usuario`,
                    `cantidad`,
                    `descripcion`,
                    `subtotal`
                )
                VALUES
                (
                    '$_SESSION[id_usuario]',
                    '1',
                    'Bonificación por bono acumulado',
                    '$bono'
                );";

        $respuesta = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql) or     die(mysqli_error($conexion));


        $_POST['total'] -= $bono; 

        if(intval($_POST['total']) < 0){
            $_POST['total'] = 0 ;
        }

        $sql = "UPDATE 
                    `lc_t_usuarios` SET 
                    `ventas_acumuladas`= 0
                    WHERE `id_usuario`= $_SESSION[id_usuario];";

        $respuesta = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql) or     die(mysqli_error($conexion));

    }else{
        //echo "NO es mayor o igual que lo necesario";
        //como no se volvio acredor de la promocion se acumula una venta     acumulada mas

        $sql = "UPDATE 
                    `lc_t_usuarios` SET 
                    `ventas_acumuladas`= (ventas_acumuladas + 1) 
                    WHERE `id_usuario`= $_SESSION[id_usuario];";

        $respuesta = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql) or     die(mysqli_error($conexion));
    }

    //die();
```

Comment: You have several SQL statements and it's not clear from your question what the problem is and I can't tell from your code because the variables and comments aren't in English. You could try telling us what your data is and what result you're looking for. You could also try http://es.stackoverflow.com/ but it's in beta.

Comment: From:
lc_t_configuracion where id_conf = 18 / How many times i needo to buy to obtain a discount

lc_t_configuracion where id_conf = 19 / % of discount

and from 

    SELECT 
                    ROUND(((SUM(total) + $_POST[total])  *     ($datos_promocion[porcentaje_bonificacion]/100)),0) as total / I obtain total in $